# Why do we create instances of classes?

Tags: c#, class, instance

I'm learning C# and I want to know **why** we create instances of classes.

```
Customer myCustomer = new Customer();
myCustomer.name = "harry";
```

When I search online I always get "How to make instances" but that's not my question.
I know how to make them.
*Why* is my question.
Is it because we use them like datatypes? Like complex datatypes.

Comment: Exactly, it's because we use them as data types.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you are building some contacts application. Then, there will be a class called Contact. You will create an instance of Contact class for each contact you need to save. You cant save all contacts in single instance. Each contact will have different attributes. Like First Name, Last Name , email, phone number etc.

In the above code example, you are trying to create an instance of customer. If you have lot of customers, then you definitely create an instance for each customer to keep track of all customers.

Answer (score 0):

Often we use a class to represent a particular entity in our system. In your example you have a class to represent a Customer. However (hopefully) you have more than one customer! To represent this you have two instances of a customer class, one for Harry and one for Jerry.

Jerry and Harry are two different customers but your system contains the same information about each (their name, customer order, recent purchases etc).

When the time comes to expand your system to include different shops you would create a new Class called `Shop` with instances representing your London, New York and Sydney stores.

Answer (score 0):

An instance of a class gets a chunk of memory allocated to it to store it's internal variables. This means that the variables of one instance are isolated from the variables of another instance.

Answer (score 0):

If it's your first object oriented programming language you're doing right by asking this, it's important to understand how this works.

A class is defined by its methods and atributes but you need to instantiate it to start using those methods and giving values to attributes, for example :

```
myCustomer.name = " harry"
```

In this case "name" is an attribute of Customer class and you set the name of harry to this one instantiated Customer only, not to the class, the class won't have any values, only defined attributes and methods.

Same thing goes with methods, for example:

```
myCustomer.setName("harry");
```

(in case the attribute "name" would be private)

you instantiate and call methods from the main class, other classes are made to define methods and attributes and then use them instantiating.

See also: [CodeProject introduction to OOP](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22769/Introduction-to-Object-Oriented-Programming-Concep#Introduction), [Wikipedia article Class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_programming)).

Comment: The class can have values though, and methods as well, without being instanced.

Answer (score 0):

Well i think you basically answered your own question no?

Its because a `class` is just a type. If i say, `Customer` came into the store today, you get an idea of a *type* of a person, a *customer*. But if i say that `"Harry"` is a customer at my store, you understand that i am only talking about one `Customer` in particular. What i say about `"Harry"` is singular to him, and has little to do with all of the other `Customers` as a whole.

```
Customer myCustomer = new Customer();
myCustomer.name = "harry";
```

I mean, its almost completely human legible. Think about it this way:

```
// Type   // instance
Color     myColor = new Color(255,0,0); // red
```